# Why this cin is not working properly?

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{

    int c;
    cout<<"enter number of test cases\n";
    cin>>c;
    while (c!=0)
    {
        string s;
        int t;
        cout<<"enter number of strings to be entered\n";
        cin>>t;
        map <string,int> a;
        map <string,int>::iterator it;    
        while ( t!= 0 )
        {
            getline(cin,s);
            it = a.find(s);
            if ( it == a.end() )
            {
                a.insert(pair<string,int>(s,1));
                cout<<"New inserted\n";
            }
            else
            {
                a[s]++;
                cout<<"Value incremented\n";
            }
            t--;
        }
        it = a.begin();
        cout<<"Value will print\n";
        while ( it != a.end() )
        {
            cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";
            it++;
        }
        c--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, I made this code which first asks for test cases, and then asks for number of strings and then sorts the strings and outputs their frequency.
Now, in this code, as soon as I hit enter after entering the number of strings, the message `New Inserted` is displayed, meaning that the new line is being put as a string in the map. Why is that happening?

Thanks!

PS: I tried putting `fflush(stdin)` before getline but it doesnt help either.

Comment: Don't mix `stdio` with `iostreams`.

Comment: I removed `stdio.h` and used `cin` in place of `scanf` ( which I did only as an attempt to make it work ) but it still doesn't.

Comment: That was not an answer, juts a general advice.

Comment: Next time, please prepare an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The whole problem could have been summarized in a 10-line program.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` reads the number from the input, and leaves a newline character behind. That newline is interpreted by the next getline, and you get an empty line at first.

**Fix 1:**
read the newline with `scanf`:

instead of reading the number only:

```
scanf("%d", &t);
```

use the following which swallows the newline as well:

```
scanf("%d\n", &t);
```

---

Anyway, it is a bad idea to mix `stdio` with `iostream` but you'd get a similar same result if you would use

```
cin >> t;
```

**Fix 2** (works with streams as well): Ignore the first line read by `getline`

---

**Fix 3**

Use `getline` to get the numbers into strings and parse them:

```
getline(cin, s);
istringstream ( s ) >> t;
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you suggest placing an additional `scanf` after getting the number of strings. Btw, even if you put, `cin` instead of `scanf`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @sarah updated to be more precise

Comment: But, why does this happen? I have removed `stdio` but it doesn't solve the problem. I can remove the first line, but why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: That's in the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: I am asking, does it happen with cin as well? Does cin shows a similar nature?

Comment: @sarah Yes, it does.